# Angularjs: access template in directive

Tags: angularjs

What I want to do is to append compiled template to some other DOM element in Angualrjs directive. Is it possible? How?

I know you can use transclude to include the template and keep content in the tag, but how do I attach my compiled template to other DOM element?

```
angular.module("my.directive")
.directive('passwordStrength', [function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: '/tpl/directive/passwordStrength.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs){
            console.log('password strength is running');
            iElement.append($template) // problem here!!!


        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Try to compile template code before appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish overall. You may want to use `ng-include` to pull in markup from a url, rather than using the `templateUrl` property, or you may want to use the `templateUrl` property on one directive, then make another directive and include that directive in the second directive. I made some sample directives to help give you ideas.

```
.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
     scope: {
       path: '=myDirective'
     },
     link: function(scope, element) {
      // rather than use `templateUrl`, I'll get markup from the path using `ng-include`
      var html = '<div ng-include="path"></div>';
      // manipulate the markup however you want to
      html+= '<p>More stuff from "myDirective"!</p>';
      // append the markup
      element.append(html);
      // compile the markup so that Angular will know about it (or use the directive `compile` rather than `link`)
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
  };
})

// this is sort of like "extending" the other directive.
.directive('myOtherDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      path: '=myOtherDirective'
    },
    template: '<p>Stuff from "myOtherDirective"></div><div my-directive="path"></div>'
  };
})
```

[**Here's a demo you can mess around with.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mxTuEnduDmSjBGqPMYTZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I need to compile the tempalte.